# Best effort secondary DHCP server with overlapping pools

Tags: networking, dhcp

I'm not experienced with DHCP configuration, and I'm looking for the best effort solution to the following non-ideal situation:

##### Devices I'm working with

- An iPhone (sometimes a DHCP server)
- Wifi router/AP in wireless repeater mode (bridges Wifi and Ethernet)
- Raspberry Pi 4 running isc dhcp server

##### Requirements

- When my phone shares its internet

  - it has address 172.20.10.1
  - the AP connects to it
  - the phone becomes a DHCP server for network 172.20.10.0/28. This DHCP server is not configurable. Presumably the pool is 172.20.10.2-14.
  - when this DHCP server appears on the network the clients should adapt quickly — not necessarily perfectly, but at least best effort, i.e. a high probability of just working.
- When my phone doesn't share internet

  - **devices on the network should still be assigned addresses via DHCP. This is what's currently not being done, i.e. the problem I thought I'd solve.**
  - this DHCP server should interfere as little as possible when the other server becomes present again
- The phone has to retain access to other devices on the network

###### What I wanted to do after reading up a bit was to...

- ...naively minimize collisions by setting the `isc` address pool to the higher half, i.e. 9-14
- ...delay offers from the `isc` server so as to "prioritize" the unconfigurable phone server. I could not find how to do that with `isc`. **Can it be done?**
- ...use short lease times from `isc`

Is there a better strategy to deal with this DHCP situation (given the constraints in hardware)?

Answer (score 1):

> ...naively minimize collisions by setting the isc address pool to the higher half, i.e. 9-14

It would be good if the DHCP server performed a collision check using ARP before issuing an address. ISC DHCP Server kind of supports this, but only using ICMP pings (which some devices may deliberately ignore, resulting in false negatives, whereas ARP queries are never ignored).

Some clients do such checks on their own, after receiving the lease and before "accepting" it. If the DHCP server supports "rapid commit", that feature should be disabled (though I don't think ISC DHCP supports that anyway).

> ...delay offers from the isc server so as to "prioritize" the unconfigurable phone server. I could not find how to do that with isc. Can it be done?

Use the `min-secs` parameter. It will make the DHCP server ignore the initial DHCPDISCOVER (which has a "seconds" field of 0), while still reacting to the following attempts.

RouterOS has an equivalent option called `delay-threshold`.

> ...use short lease times from isc

Probably not needed if the ISC DHCP server mimics the iPhone's configuration anyway. Usually it doesn't matter which device issues the lease, as long as the subnet and the default gateway are right. (Yes, the `isc` server can advertise 172.20.10.1 (iphone) as the gateway – it doesn't have to be the DHCP server itself.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your suggestions. Regarding the short leases, my thinking was that the phone probably won't check if an address is used before offering it to someone else, so I'd need short leases to resolve a collision quickly (?) Regarding the default gateway, it kind of works to offer a non-existent default gateway from isc, but it will break applications (e.g. iOS will prioritize WiFi over cellular if it has a default route, so you end up with no internet access). To complicate matters, the WiFi repeater has started to offer addresses despite configured to the opposite ‍♂️ Asus...

Comment: Have you considered getting a dedicated 4G/LTE modem with its own data plan?

Comment: Yes, I know I can pay to have it solved. That way I can also avoid being introduced to unfamiliar topics, but I wanted to take the opportunity to learn a little about dhcp and make the best of what I already have (and which vendors to avoid).

Comment: A follow up question: when you mention `min-secs`, will that also prevent `isc` from replying first when the client renews its lease? It doesn't seem to work — my clients just renew what they got from `isc` initially, despite the presence of the other DHCP server.

Comment: No, I don't think so – AFAIK, min-secs only applies to broadcast discover packets; renewal means the client skips discovery and goes straight to the lease-request step (DHCPREQUEST), which it'll unicast to the same server that it originally got the lease from, thus no discovery needed.

Comment: Right, in that case I guess my problem is unsolvable unless I always assign a default gateway even when there's none present.